# Get specific value when trying to access outside of matrix

Tags: python, numpy, matrix

Can I receive a specified value (0 for example) when trying to get a value outside of a NumPy matrix?

For example:

```
#getItem - some method which do what i want
a = numpy.array([[1, 2], [3, 4]])
getItem(a, 1, 1) # == 4
getItem(a, -1, 1) # == 0
```

Of course I can do it by hand, but in Python these approaches may have bad performance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use a `try`/`except` block to handle invalid indices

```
def getItem(a, i, j):
    try:
        return a[i,j]
    except IndexError:
        return 0

>>> getItem(a, 1, 1)
4
>>> getItem(a, 2, 5)
0
```

Comment: Thank you for answer. Is there no built-in method?

Comment: @Dark_Daiver To index an array, the class's [`operator.__getitem__`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html#operator.__getitem__). is called. This operator is deliberately defined to throw an `IndexError` exception when you index out of bounds. If you choose that you'd like to `return 0` in this case, you are free to write a function like above. But Python doesn't want to force this behavior on everyone, because it may not make sense to `return 0` in many cases.